# Gnuplot date vs date

Tags: gnuplot

How does one plot the following data in gnuplot:

```
101,2018,116,1500,3.457
101,2018,116,1515,3.456
101,2018,116,1530,3.458
101,2018,116,1545,3.458
101,2018,116,1600,3.457
```

I need to plot data (column 5) vs time (columns 2, 3, & 4). Column 2 is year, 3 Julian day, and 4 is HHMM. Here is what I have tried

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y,%j,%H%M"
set xrange ["1/15/2018":"8/02/2018"]
set yrange [0:5]

plot 'du1piezometerslong050318.dat' using 2:5 title 'July time series' with lp lw 4 pt 7 ps 0.75
```

Answer (score 2):

By default gnuplot expects space-separated data. So you will need this:

```
set datafile separator ","
```

Then day 116 in the input data is 26th April, so the xrange of January to February would not include that. The format for the specified xrange should be the same as the timefmt (year,day,hour/minute):

```
set xrange ["2018,116,1500":"2018,116,1600"]
```

The yrange works, but is too big to really see differences, it's probably OK to not set a yrange and let gnuplot figure it out itself.

The final gnuplot script would be:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y,%j,%H%M"
set xrange ["2018,116,1500":"2018,116,1600"]
set datafile separator ","
plot 'data.dat' using 2:5 title 'time series' with lp lw 4 pt 7 ps 0.75
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
#specify that our columns are separated with ','
set datafile separator ","

set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y,%j,%H%M"

#specify the output formatting of the x-tics
set format x "%Y-%m-%d"

#set xrange in a format compatible with 'timefmt' above
set xrange ["2018,116,0000":"2018,117,0000"]
set yrange [0:5]

#assembly the specified timefmt from input columns
plot 'test.dat' using (sprintf('%04d,%03d,%04d',$2,$3,$4)):5 w lp
```